# VBA-Excel; JSON-request gives an error because of 0 in cells instead of values

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have written the following VBA-macro

```
Sub getMatches()

Dim strURL As String
Dim strJSON As String
Dim strCompetition As Integer  
Dim strSeason As Integer 
Dim strMatchDay As Integer
Dim i As Integer

'strURL = "https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/2021/matches?matchday=1&season=2019"
strURL = "https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/" & strSeason & "/matches?matchday=" & strMatchDay & "&season=" & strSeason
strCompetition = Range("B2").Value  
strSeason = Range("B4").Value
strMatchDay = Range("B6").Value
MsgBox strCompetition
MsgBox strSeason
MsgBox strMatchDay
MsgBox strURL


Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "Get", strURL
MyRequest.setRequestHeader "X-Auth-Token", "personal_code"
MyRequest.Send
Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.ResponseText)
MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText
```

Running this script, gives me the following output:

```
MsgBox strCompetition
```

[image]

```
MsgBox strSeason
```

[image]

```
MsgBox strMatchDay
```

[image]

```
MsgBox strURL
```

[image]

Why does the URL not contain the variables I declared earlier?
I want the URL to defined as follows: *"https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/2021/matches?matchday=1&season=2019"*

Comment: Because you concatenate your URL before you set the values of your variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the values of your variables after putting them into the URL. Just move the URL creation line to after you've assigned all the other variables (ditto with the matchday variable).

```
strCompetition = Range("B2").Value  
strSeason = Range("B4").Value
strMatchDay = Range("B6").Value

matchday=" & strMatchDay & "&season=" & strSeason
strURL = "https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/" & strSeason & "/matches?matchday=" & strMatchDay & "&season=" & strSeason
```